# How to return a value from Dialog to Main?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two files and I want to return an array from Dialog of Bitacora to Main. In some part of the Main code calls Bitacora. Bitacora have a textEdit. I need to return these values.

I hope that you can help me guys.

**File: Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from dbFuncs import *
from demoUI import *
from PandasModel import *
from dataLogger import *
from bitacorasend import Ui_Dialog


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        #QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        '''Variables for DB'''

        '''Table Config'''    
        self.dataTable.setColumnCount(1)    
        self.dataTable.setRowCount(5)
        self.dataTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Medición"])
        self.dataTable.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.dataTable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.dataTable.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        '''Buttons signals'''
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.savePressed)


    def bitacora(self):
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog,["data","data","data","data"])
        Dialog.exec_()

    def savePressed(self):
        self.bitacora()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**File: Bitacora.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    #import time
    class Ui_Dialog(object):
        def setupUi(self, Dialog, datos):
            self.data = datos
            self.Dialog = Dialog
            Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
            Dialog.resize(617, 405)
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(10)
            self.label.setFont(font)
            self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(16)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
            self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
            self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
            self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label_3.setFont(font)
            self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
            self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
            self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
            self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label_4.setFont(font)
            self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
            self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
            self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
            self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
            self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
            self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

            self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
            self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.save)
            self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


        def save(self):
            print("Return here")
            self.Dialog.close()

        def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
            self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Punto Fuera de Control"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Bitacora de Proceso"))
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cualquier cambio en  mano de obra, materiales, medio ambiente, métodos o máquinas debe ser anotado"))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Causa:"))
            self.textEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", ""))
            self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Correcciones:"))
            self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", ""))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I updated, the interactions are with the button"Guardar" in Main and "Ok" in Bitacora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
#from dbFuncs import *
#from demoUI import *
#from PandasModel import *
#from dataLogger import *
#import time

#from bitacorasend import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog, datos):
        self.data = datos
        self.Dialog = Dialog
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(617, 405)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.save)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


    def save(self):
        print("Return here")
        self.Dialog.close()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Punto Fuera de Control"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Bitacora de Proceso"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cualquier cambio en  mano de obra, materiales, medio ambiente, métodos o máquinas debe ser anotado"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Causa:"))
        self.textEdit.setText(_translate("Dialog", ""))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Correcciones:"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", ""))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):     #, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        #QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
#        self.setupUi(self)
        '''Variables for DB'''

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.dataTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self) 
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("saveButton", self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.dataTable)
        layout.addWidget(self.saveButton)


        '''Table Config'''
        self.dataTable.setColumnCount(1)    
        self.dataTable.setRowCount(5)
        self.dataTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Medición"])
        self.dataTable.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.dataTable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.dataTable.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        '''Buttons signals'''
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.savePressed)

    def bitacora(self):
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog,["data","data","data","data"])
        Dialog.exec_()

        print(ui.textEdit.toPlainText())                                  # <---
        print(ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText())                                # <---

    def savePressed(self):
        self.bitacora()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: @CharlyMtzP  I didn’t fix anything. I just added two lines that marked `# <---`.